# JAX-RS get body of POST request in java.lang.Object

Tags: json, jax-rs

I want to create a POST endpoint in JAX-RS (CXF implementation) where I can read a JSON request body in java.lang.Object class since that JSON can be anything and I don't know the schema beforehand. I.e.

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public void register(Object request) {

}
```

This solution results in runtime error:

```
No message body reader has been found for class java.lang.Object, ContentType: application/json
2018-03-10 16:52:49.156 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] ERROR c.i.i.c.w.r.e.JsonProcessingExceptionMapper - af04c2db-9e87-4b69-963d-272caa6b1329 - WebApplicationException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1346)
```

Only thing that is working is to use a JsonNode object but I would like to avoid it since it messes up my swagger model with a bunch of properties.

Comment: Maybe use `Map<String,?>`? FYI, I don't know what JSON engine CXF uses, but some do not support maps (like EclipseLink Moxy), so if this doesn't work switch to Jackson

Comment: Yes,this is what I used finally. i confirm that it works )